# Show the determinant of the matrix is $(a − b)(b − c)(c − a)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Show that the determinant$$
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         1 & a & a^2 \\
>         1 & b & b^2 \\
>         1 & c & c^2 \\
>         \end{vmatrix} = (a − b)(b − c)(c − a)$$

Using the Cofactor expansion I've got $a((b-c)(b+c) + a(c-b)) + b(c(c-b))$ but I dont know what else to do.

Comment: It's a polynomial in $a,b,c$ of third degree which is zero if $a=b$, $a=c$, or $b=c$. So it clearly has to be a constant times $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would rather phrase that as: it's a polynomial of second degree in $a$ with obvious roots $b,c$, so it has to be of the form $f(b,c) \cdot (a-b)(a-c)$. By symmetry in $b,c$ (or by direct inspection) it follows that $f(b,c)=c-b$. This would avoid misinterpreting it as "*if $p(a,b,c) = 0$ $\implies$ $q(a,b,c)=0$ then $p \mid q$*" which does not hold true in general for polynomials in multiple variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substract first row from second and third ones and get:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&a&a^2\\
0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\
0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1&a&a^2\\
0&1&b+a\\
0&1&c+a\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}
1&b+a\\
1&c+a\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)\left(\begin{vmatrix}
1&b\\
1&c\end{vmatrix}+\overbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
1&a\\
1&a\end{vmatrix}}^{=0}\right)=$$

$$=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$$

Comment: Oh..... looks really simple now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It should be said that it is a very classical determinant: Vandermonde determinant (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant)